# ReactJs routing: Setting-up a very basic private route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

> App.js

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import ParentComponent from "./Components/nestedComponents/ParentComponent";
import NavBar from "./Components/Shared/NavBar";

//Protecting a route
import PrivateRoute from "./common/PrivateRoute";
import ProtectedComponent from "./Components/Protected/ProtectedComponent";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" name="Home" component={ParentComponent} />
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/protectedRoute"
            component={ProtectedComponent}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> ProtectedComponent.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function ProtectedComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      This is a protected component. It can only be accessed under certain
      conditions.
    </div>
  );
}
```

> PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (false ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />)}
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

For the time being, depending on the boolean value inside this statement:

```
render={props => (false ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />)}
```

If it's false, the router will redirect to **"/"** or it will redirect to the **ProtectedComponent** which is passed to **PrivateRoute** in **App.js**.

So if I click here on **ProtectedComponent on the right**, it should behave as I just mentioned.
[image]
However, when I click, I do not get redirected to **"/"** when the boolean value is **false** and I do not get directed **ProtectedComponent** when the boolean value is **true**. Just **nothing** gets rendered.
[image]
Here's the link to the [Github project](https://github.com/AGSTRANGER/react_router_dom_nested_routing/settings)

Comment: `If it's false, the router will redirect to "/" `  but your code does vise versa :)

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi oops yes, my bad :)